# square-connect quering for results in Interval

Tags: square-connect

I need to query in 5 minutes or 60  minutes intervals and get data in increments, is there a way to do that ?

Also on the Order data how can I find out the Order ful-fillment time  ?

Answer (score 0):

The [List Payments](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#get-payments) and [List Refunds](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#get-refunds) endpoints let you specify optional `begin_time` and `end_time` parameters in your request. You can set the `begin_time` to only retrieve results that have been created since your last request. This will let you query at any interval you choose.

These parameters are unfortunately not available for the [List Orders](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#get-orders) endpoint, however you can set the `order` parameter to `DESC` so that the newest orders always appear first in the returned array. Simply loop through the array until you encounter an order you've seen before.

[`Order`](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#datatype-order) objects do not include a field that indicates when the order was fulfilled, however the `updated_at` field indicates when the order was last updated in any way, including fulfilling it. You can check whether the order's state is `COMPLETED`, which probably indicates the `updated_at` field indicates fulfillment.

Comment: How much duration would I get for the orders data using this approach ?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure what you mean by "how much duration."

Comment: How far back will the order data go, if I use the ListOrders endpoint?

Comment: The List Orders endpoint returns ALL of a merchant's orders, but paginates its results if there are more orders than the number you provide for the limit parameter (or 100 by default). Pagination behavior is described here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#pagination